# Advantages of SYB (scrap your boilerplate) over GHC Generics

Tags: haskell, scrap-your-boilerplate, ghc-generics

Are any tasks that are possible only with SYB, or are much easier with it, when compared to GHC Generics?

Answer (score 3):

GHC Generics is a rather verbose way to perform basically any query or traversal.  For example, consider a language AST with `Stmt` and `Expr` types that both derive `Typeable`, `Generic`, and `Data`:

```
data Stmt = ... lots of constrs ...
data Expr = Const Int
          | ... lots of other constrs ...
```

How do you leverage SYB to get all constants starting from either `Expr` or `Stmt`?  Something like:

```
getConst (Const i) = [i]
getConst _         = []

getAllConst = everything (++) (mkQ getConst)
```

Contrast this with the typical use of Generics requiring two classes, a traversal over the sum of products representation, and instantiate the class N times for the N types needing traversed.  Where SYB, and indeed most generic systems, fall flat is in [performance](http://michaeldadams.org/papers/tyb/).